# WSO2 ESB handle JSON Response with text/html header

Tags: json, wso2-esb

The REST API which I'm calling is returning a JSON message with a text/html header (which I know is pretty lame).

I have enabled the builder in the carbon.xml for the incoming response to be handled.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

If the response is an XML I can do a xpath base64 decode and get the response and work on it.

Because the response in JSON format I'm getting the below error even though I get the binary value of it.

Expected JSON message - `{"message":"Success!","result":"logadded","status":3,"response_code":200}`

Received binary - `CgoJeyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiU3VjY2VzcyEiLCJyZXN1bHQiOiJsb2cgYWRkZWQiLCJzdGF0dXMiOjMsInJlc3BvbnNlX2NvZGUiOjIwMH0`

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-12-22 08:58:49,788] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
```

Will be please if anyone can help me on how I can get the JSON response.

Comment: Will be pleased if the solution can be without writing a calss mediator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand why you are using BinaryRelayBuilder message builder, you should consider `org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder` or `org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder` (see [JSON+Support](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support)).

An other solution with BinaryRelayBuilder is to use builder mediator in your mediation :

```
<builder>
    <messageBuilder contentType="" class="" [formatterClass=""]/>
</builder>
```

Comment: You answer helped me to find a solution, thanks a lot Jean.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i was calling an endpoint that return text/html, and WSO2 was throwing an exception when receiving the response, so i solve it by adding the following entries to conf/axis2/axis2.xml, each in the correct section:

```
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html" 
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="text/html" 
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```